# Compare two strings in java, how to print equals words

Tags: java, string, startswith, ends-with

In java I got 2 strings  (each contains a list of words for example ab,ac,ad,bb,bc,bd and second string which contains user input (for example word "a") I want to compare those 2 strings and get text that first string contain (like if startswith return true I want to print out word that matches for example in my case ab,ac,ad) anyone know how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split` and iterate

```
String input = "a";
String str = "ab,ac,ad,bb,bc,bd";
for (String s: str.split(",")) {
    if (s.startsWith(input)) {
        System.out.println("String " + s + " starts with " + input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, this was what I mean :D